# How to permanently change a PATH variable in Debian

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables, paths

I'm trying to change the directory that is accessed when I call `blender` in my terminal.

This is currently where it is:

```
...$ which blender
/usr/bin/blender
```

And I'd like to instead use the version of blender I have located in:

```
home/myname/tools/Blender-2.79-CellBlender/blender
```

I understand that similar questions have been asked, but I can't find anything that helps with my beginner level.

I'm using Debian 9.

```
...$ echo $PATH
/home/myname/tools/cmake/bin/:/<private>/home/myname/<private>/:/home/myname/tools/anaconda3/bin:/home/myname/tools/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

**Question 1:** Why don't I see the "/usr/bin/blender" path when I call echo $PATH?

**Question 2:** How do I permanently change the directory that's called when I type "blender" into the command line?

---

I've tried

```
export PATH=$PATH: ~/tools/Blender-2.79-CellBlender/blender
```

which works, but this doesn't help because:

1. it doesn't permanently change the PATH, and
2. since I already have "/usr/bin/blender" in the PATH (though I don't know how to see that!), it will always go to the first directory in the PATH, which isn't the one I want.

Comment: To make it permanent you need to add the line to `.profile` or `.bashrc`

Comment: `/usr/bin/blender` is there because in `$PATH` is set `/usr/bin`

Comment: Sorry, but could you elaborate what you mean by that? Where in .bashrc would I add the line, and what line are you referring to? Thanks!

Comment: I've answered, hope it's clear, but I realize now that you are using debian, wich is off topic here in AU. So it's possible that this question is gonna be closed. You can ask again in [U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer and the heads up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Question 2: How do I permanently change the directory that's called when I type "blender" into the command line?

To add your path permanently you have to edit your `~/.bashrc`(and you may have to log out/log in):

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Add at the bottom:

```
export PATH="~/tools/Blender-2.79-CellBlender:$PATH"
```

As @bac0n explains in the comments, the order is important. As `/usr/bin` takes precedence if further configurations add the new path at the *end* of `$PATH`, the trick is to add the new path *before* `/usr/bin` (the order always left to right).

> Question 1: Why don't I see the "/usr/bin/blender" path when I call echo $PATH?

You don't see `blender` because it's the executable file like are all the others under the path, being the *path* `/usr/bin`, which is set in you `$PATH` variable

Comment: I included the line you suggested at the bottom of .bashrc, but that doesn't seem to change anything. 

"which blender" still results in "/usr/bin/blender". Do I not have to first remove that path directory in order to have the other directory work?

Comment: order of the paths is important..

Comment: Yes, I guess `/usr/bin` takes precedence. But remember, the path is not `/usr/bin/blender`, it's just `/usr/bin`, under wich are all the executables.

Comment: @bac0n added your insight to the answer.

Comment: I recommend defining and modifying environment variables in your `~/.profile` and keep the shell rc for configuration options that are specific to that program.

Comment: Yes, so I understand that order matters, but I don't know how to use that knowledge to solve my problem. I placed the "export PATH= ... " line before any other export commands in .bashrc, and while that does put "home/myname/tools/Blender-2.79-CellBlender/blender/" at the front of my path (as seen by "echo $PATH"), it doesn't change my blender command: "which blender" still yields "/usr/bin/blender".

Comment: Also, I don't have a .profile file in my home directory, I only can find one in /snap/core/8039/etc/skel/.profile

Comment: after you made changes to .bashrc you need to `source ./.bashrc` next you can try `hash`

Comment: @Otherness You have to add the *path* without the executable. I edited the question and you shoud edit too: `export PATH="~/tools/Blender-2.79-CellBlender:$PATH"`. Now issue the command `which -a blender` and you should see all the paths, the first the one you exported.

Comment: The answer I meant

Comment: Yes! Thanks @guillermochamorro !!